# Mule ActiveMQ connector not able to reconnect after broker restart

Tags: mule, activemq-artemis, mule-esb

I am using the ActiveMQ Connector to connect to an ActiveMQ Artemis broker. While Mule and ActiveMQ Artemis are running if suddenly I stop and start again or restart the ActiveMQ Artemis instance alone then Mule is not able to connect again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure appropriate re-connection strategy, in the global elements properties JMS Config, Advanced tab. change it to forever and should work.